# Zlib not installed in Cygwin - Kaldi

Tags: dependencies, cygwin, zlib, kaldi

I wanted to install Kaldi in Cygwin environment.

I have installed all the necessary dependencies and packages.

When I run check_dependencies, I am getting error like,

**check_dependencies.sh: zlib is not installed**

**./check_dependencies.sh: The following prerequisites are missing; install them first:
   zlib1g-d**

But this issue seems to be persisting despite the fact, I have selected all dependencies that contain Zlib.

Can anyone please help me, why this is happening?

I have searched the internet and this forum. But nothing seems to be satisfying.

Kindly please help me with this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3pk4.png)

Comment: Never ever try to use cygwin for recent thing. Install Linux at least in virtual machines.

Comment: @nicolay-shmyrev Please be useful. Not every one agrees with your opinion nor can install a virtual machine on the computer

Comment: The script seems to have some assumption about the system that do not fit with Cygwin: it does not recognize g++, an that is strange also for a Linux system. It requires the MKL library, on Cygwin Lapack and Openblas are available. The `zlib` header and import library are in the package `zlib-devel` but I suspect the script is looking for a different method to find packages and it is not looking at the files itself. `zlib1g-dev` is surely not the name of a package in Cygwin, but it is in `Debian` and derived Distro. Cygwin package names are more in line with `Fedora` style.

Comment: Yeah, most likely you need to install the `zlib-devel` package.  Without seeing what this custom `check_dependencies.sh` script is doing it's hard to say much else.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but installing Pillow under cygwin. As it was mentioned in the comments above by Iguananaut, the development package zlib-devel is needed. So, I just went to cygwin setup program, selected this package and installed it. The tried again to install Pillow in the cygwin terminal. The problem was solved.